# unity 3d rotate object (space.self) toward player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need your help please. 
i want an object to rotate in Y axis (space.self) toward the player position.
 i have already tried this code, it works but i think there is a bug in it because the object keep changing position slowly.

```
public Transform _Playertrs;
public float RotationSpeed = 10f;

private Quaternion _LookRotation;
private Vector3 _direction;
private bool Patroling = true;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    _direction = (_Playertrs.position - transform.position).normalized;
    _LookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_direction);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,  _LookRotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
}
```

thank you guys for your answers, the rotation is working perfectly now, but the problem is the object keep moving from its position even that i don't have any movement code, watch the video to understand pls
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gys5xYQ5psw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: *"the object keep changing position slowly"* What do you mean by that? Your code doesn't contain anything that could change the position.

Comment: hello, I see that this is your first question on Stackoverflow. Welcome! If one of the answer provided solved your problem, you can **accept** it to mark the topic as solved. (see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more explanation on accepting answers )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this is taken from the Unity [Quaternion.LookRotation()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) official documentation, you can just simply apply the Quaternion that you have `_LookRotation` and apply it to your desired `transform.rotation` as such `transform.rotation = _LookRotation;`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    void Update() {
        Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer the rotation is working, but the object is moving please see the video to understand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gys5xYQ5psw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @KhalidGu are you by any chance applying these to nested (child) gameobjects, whose parent could be moving, hence making them all move ? Are you also sur you are using WorldSpace and not Local ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be instantaneous, replace

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,  _LookRotation, Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed);
```

by

```
transform.rotation = _LookRotation;
```

The Slerp function gives an intermediate point between the to rotation to make a smooth effect.

Comment: thank you for your answer the rotation is working, but the object is moving please see the video to understand 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gys5xYQ5psw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: The code you showed just touches the rotation. Is there something else in this file that you didn't post here? Is there another script attached to these objects? What happens if you disable this script in the editor before running? (disable=untick the box with you script name in unity inspector)